# Rails how to access attr_name inside other loop? Column method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My loop:

```
<% @products.first.attributes.except('name', 'created_at','updated_at','id').each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
<tr>
    <td><span><%= t(attr_name) %></span></td>
    <td class="middle">Pr. x</td>
    <%= @products.each do |f| %>
    <td class="last"><%= f.attr_name %> ,-</td>
    <% end %>
<tr>
<% end %>
```

Then I get this error: `undefined method attr_name for #<Product:0x3adc850`

How do I use the column method with attr_name? I have tried things like `f."#{attr_name}"` without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
<%= @products.each do |f| %>
   <td class="last"><%= f.send attr_name %> ,-</td>
<% end %>
```

And you should rename `f` into `product` (`f` is generally used for form builders)